# Error exit code 1 code showing in Jenkins Consiole output ( I do not want to see it )

Tags: shell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I have a job running in the Jenkins pipeline and the output is showing error exit code 1 because am using if statement to create NOT_BUILT in the stage. Is there any other way to not see  the work error exit code 1. I do not want to use When statement but if possible to still use IF statement and have a blank stage but without this message error exit code 1 in the console output.
This is my script below :

```
if(route53 == 'false' ) { 
    catchError(buildResult: 'SUCCESS', stageResult: 'NOT_BUILT') {   
       sh "exit 1"
    }
}
else if(route53 == 'true' && all == "Yes" ) {            
    catchError(buildResult: 'SUCCESS', stageResult: 'NOT_BUILT') {
        sh "exit 1"
    }
}
```

The result in the pipeline console output is showing this, the stage graphic is fine as it is showing a blank stage but the console output error code is what I really want to manipulate.

```
output result
    + exit 1
    [Pipeline] }
    [Pipeline] }
    ERROR: script returned exit code 1
    [Pipeline] }
    ERROR: script returned exit code 1
    [Pipeline] }
    ERROR: script returned exit code 1
    [Pipeline] }
```

Comment: Are you using scripted or declarative pipeline?

Comment: @Noam. I am using declarative pipeline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using declarative pipelines the *NOT_BUILT* state is preserved to a stage  the was not executed because its `when` directive was evaluated as `false`, and there is not direct way to set it except with the `catchError` workaround. (btw you can control the error message by using `error('Your Message')` instead of `exit 1`)

Therefore, it is easiest to achieve using the `when` directive and also makes your pipeline more readable. If you insist on using `if` statements you can still use them inside a `when` directive with the generic **`expression`** option which allows you to run any groovy code and calculate the relevant Boolean value according to your needs.
So you can still use your original code and just update it to return a Boolean:

```
stage('Conditional stage') {
    when {
        expression {
            if(route53 == 'false' ) {
                return false
            }
            else if(route53 == 'true' && all == "Yes" ) {
                return false
            }
            return true
        }
    }
    steps {
        ...
    }
}
```